# Putting Complex numbers in the form a+bi

Tags: complex-numbers

So I have two problems:

1. $e^{\pi/4i}(1+i)$
2. $(1+i)^{1000}$ with the hint to use the polar form

its unclear how to get the $4i$ out of the exponent

Comment: You've asked enough questions here to know that you should format the mathematics with mathjax (from now on). https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Is it suppose to be $\frac{\pi}{4i}$ or $\frac{\pi}{4}i$?

Comment: the edited version is correct

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

> $$i^2=-1$$$$\frac{1}{i}=-i$$

More hint?

> $$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$

More More hint?

> $$z=|z|e^{i\text{Arg} z}$$

Approximately-the-solution hint?

> $$(1+i)=\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{π}{4}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Just $$e^{\frac{\pi}{4}i}=\cos\frac{\pi}{4}+i\sin\frac{\pi}{4}.$$
Also, use $$(1+i)^4=(2i)^2=-4.$$

Answer (score 1):

For b write $1+i=\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$